# How do I calculate average over time properly?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a housing data set and I am trying to calculate the average housing price by year and month.

Here is the line of code I attempted to use:

```
housing_data[,list(avg=mean(housing_data$price)), by = list(date(as.POSIXct(housing_data$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")))]
```

However, this was my output:

```
           date      avg
  1: 2004-04-11 612622.2
  2: 2005-07-17 612622.2
  3: 2003-06-01 612622.2
  4: 2004-01-18 612622.2
  5: 2006-01-29 612622.2
 ---                    
159: 2004-03-07 612622.2
160: 2005-08-14 612622.2
161: 2006-03-12 612622.2
162: 2005-10-23 612622.2
163: 2006-04-16 612622.2
```

I don't understand how I am calculating the mean incorrectly. Also, how can I remove the days from the data and calculate the average from just year/month only.

Comment: You can convert your data to an `xts` object and then use `apply.monthly(yourxtsobject, colMeans)`

Comment: your dataset looks like a data.table. then maybe `housing_data[,list(avg=mean(price)), by=format(date, "%Y%m")]`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(month_year = format(date_col, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(value_avg = mean(value))
```

**Output is:**

```
  month_year value_avg
1 2018-05         14.5
2 2018-06         43.5
3 2018-07         59.5
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame(date_col=seq.Date(as.Date("2018/5/4"), by="day", length.out = 60),
                 value = 1:60)
```